# If wifi ap isn't associated with any device and send mulitcast packt to air, is it successful? if not successful, what should I do?should I

Tags: wifi, multicast, openwrt

If wifi ap isn't associated with any device and send mulitcast packt to air, is it successful?  if it's not successful, what should I do on openwrt?

Comment: This question might be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it's not about programming; it might belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com). If you think it is, please describe what you tried to solve your problem, preferably by a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

No, *in most situations*, a client must be authenticated and associated with an AP (Access Point) in order to send/receive *data* that is not related to the authentication and association process.

The clients can join an IBSS network and you can send frames to the broadcast address of the WiFi interface you are using. Though it might not be what you are looking for.

More information on what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: if  no any station associated wifi router, will program running on router multicast UDP  to 2.4/5G wifi?   will I catpure these multicast package over the air with WIFI sniffer?

Comment: As long as it's on the same channel, it will probably capture some, but it is not guaranteed.